# Android support library rev.47 update failure

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-studio-2.3

Whenever i was trying to update my Support library from Android SDK manager to revision 47, I am getting error. Download failed every-time. I can not update my Android support library revision to 47.

[image]
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar issue below worked for me. The solution for this is:

> Run Android Studio as Administrator.
>
> Rerun the update.
>
> It will work.